# svelte crashes on client render

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a sveltekit project that is fairly basic in it's function.

It works "fine" when rendering on the backend, but as soon as it switches over to client side it crashes. And if I disable ssr, then I get stuck with a white page and errors in the console log.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
proxy.js:15 
[HMR][Svelte] Unrecoverable error in <Root>: next update will trigger a full reload

root.svelte:46 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: options.hydrate only works if the component was compiled with the `hydratable: true` option
    at Object.claim [as l] (root.svelte:46:13)
    at init (index.mjs:1812:40)
    at new Root (root.svelte:16:25)
    at createProxiedComponent (svelte-hooks.js:245:9)
    at new ProxyComponent (proxy.js:239:20)
    at new Proxy<Root> (proxy.js:339:11)
    at Renderer._init (start.js:664:15)
    at Renderer.update (start.js:615:9)
    at async Router._navigate (start.js:267:3)
```

and I have no idea what I've done wrong or even where to begin looking, as I've never really seen this type of error before.

Also I am not using any component library in my project, but I have some components in the `src/lib/` folder that is created and linked by sveltekit

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what caused the issue!

The error only occurs if the sveltekit project is part of a npm workspace.

So in a sense, fairly simple to fix by just removing it and managing it separately.

Comment: Can you add some example how did you fix the issue?

Comment: for me it only applied to npm workspaces. And it was a pretty simple fix to remove my svelte project from the root `package.json` file, and thus it was no longer part of the npm workspace

Comment: this answer doesn't mean anything.

Comment: it means that at the time of answering sveltekit did not support npm workspaces https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces